# How to solve this error "('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext)') isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient'"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, dart-pub

I use flutter version 2.2.1

File : Main.dart

[image]

This is message error
[image]

How to solve this error?

Comment: 1. Don't post screenshots of code and messages; those cannot be searched. 2. As shown by the error message, `HttpOverrides.createHttpClient` takes a `SecurityContext?`, not a `SecurityContext`.

Answer (score 52):

Change SecurityContext to SecurityContext?.

Comment: Ratted my brain for a solid 30 minutes before I saw this answer. I cannot believe it was something this simple (and stupid on my part). Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> Change SecurityContext to SecurityContext?

here is the update code:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
return super.createHttpClient(context)
..badCertificateCallback =
(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).