Flutter Phone Application Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'xxxxxxx' error
I am getting an error from the API I am using in the application I made in Flutter. It works fine in the web and desktop application, but when I start the phone application, it gives an error.
Error:

Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'xxxxxx' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7),

Code:
 try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': basicAuth,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
      );

I also added the internet permission code but it didn't work.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application


I`m not sure, but check you have a proper internet connection on your mobile device.

My internet connection is stable. VPN is also open on my computer.

Add http override class in your application
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369657/17568395

I already added it but it doesn't work.
